# query regarding sessions in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

In my web application I am using sessions for storing the user specific data for persisting the data in between the postbacks.

I would like to know the difference between storing the data in sessions as

```
Session["selectedItem"] = somevalue;
```

and

```
Session["UserName"]["SelectedItem"] = somevalue;
```

where I have a session named Session["UserName"] which stores the name of the user who is logged in.

If i just go into more depth lets say if there are 2 users one logs into firefox and other internet explorer, will there be any conflict if i store the value in the first way meaning the session data is overwritten or shared, and this conflict would be resolved if i use sessions in second way.

Is there any noticeable difference in the way session variable is stored between these 2 session implementations or are they just identical ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sessions are unique per user, so there's no need to key your Session variables by user.

Comment: Is there any difference between these 2 formats in terms of storing the session variable ? or are they just identical ?

Comment: They behave completely differently. Session is basically a collection of key-value pairs, where a new instance is created for each unique visitor. In the 1st line, the value being stored is a string. The 2nd line there will only be a single key/value pair created, but the value would be another associative array. It shouldn't even compile the way it's written. Everything returned from Session is a generic object that has to be cast to a specific type, and you can't index into an object.

Answer (score 4):

Data stored in a session is, per definition, stored against a specific user - and it will work regardless of whether your user has been authenticated or not (if your user is anonymous the server will still set a cookie in the user's browser with a unique id for the user's session).

The session object provides a simple one-dimensional collection for storing data, meaning that you can only store data in the session by providing a single key, e.g.

```
Session["myKey"] = myObject;
```

Of course, if myObject is an array or another collection then you can reference elements within myObject like this:

```
Session["myKey"][0];
Session["myKey"]["anotherKey"];
```

Comment: `Session["myKey"][0]` would throw a compile error. You'd have to explicitly cast `Session["myKey"]` as an array or other type of indexable class first, which would get a lot uglier: `((MyClass)Session["myKey"])[0];`

Comment: Yes, absolutely - you're right. Massive oversight on my part. My point is, though, that you _can_ do it. In this particular scenario it isn't really necessary, so I'd avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

The session is generally tied to a particular browser through cookies and is isolated from other sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Hope following points clear your doubts

1. You will get a new session/session ID when using different browsers
2. If you are using the same browser (tabs or multiple instances) and your session is set to use cookies, by default cookies will be shared among all tabs and/or instances of a browser
3. If you want a different session when using the same browser you will need to use cookieless sessions.